# Who painted Data's paintings?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-data, behind-the-scenes, props

Several times in ST:TNG, we see Data painting.  While I don't rule out the possibility that these paintings were done by Brent Spiner, I suspect they were either created for the show by someone or found by a Paramount propmaster.  Do we have any information on who painted the paintings in the series?  In particular, I'd like to know more about *The Battle of HarOs*, from [S7E11 (Parallels)](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Parallels_(episode)).

[image: picture of painting, from https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Battle_of_HarOs?file=Battle_of_HarOs.jpg]

Comment: I fully suspect @Valorum will have answer for you shortly.

Comment: There is http://www.stim.com/Stim-x/0996September/Eyebot/datapainting-intro.html, according to which Data’s paintings were “actually created by scenic artists Jim Magdaleno, Alan Kobayashi, and "Star Trek" aesthetic visionary Mike Okuda himself”; which seems plausible, but there is no reference. Christie’s [sold four paintings from _Birthright_](http://www.christies.com/lotfinder/lot/datas-paintings-4780095-details.aspx), stating that they were “created in the _Star Trek_ art department”. Nothing about this particular painting, though.

Comment: There is a lot of art at http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/database/space_art_tng.htm, including one of Data’s paintings (but again not this one), which was actually done by Rick Sternbach.

Comment: The abstract of Spot (the cat) is credited to Wendy Drapanas in the *Star Trek Companion* - https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ge_QJ2eM3KcC&pg=PT467&lpg=PT467&dq=star+trek+data+paintings+prop+artist&source=bl&ots=DQwmGNk3vf&sig=hKhDpPwBf_FA2taqM0FzJJ0lK7c&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwieiOf8tKPRAhUlBMAKHUR6CcM4ChDoAQgyMAM#v=onepage&q=star%20trek%20data%20paintings%20prop%20artist&f=false

Answer (score 7):

In ""11001001", we see that at least one of Data's paintings was painted by the staff, and they mention that they painted later Data paintings:

> Rick Sternbach: *"Oh, I'm sure that the F&SF cover probably inspired me a bit. I don't recall exactly (eggs-actly?), but it sounds plausible. :)*"
>
> *"I don't recall who had the specific idea for painting the eggs on clear plexiglas. I don't remember doing any kind of production sketch of the set-up (although I might have), so the idea have come from the producers or someone else in props or set decoration. I remember being given the plex and adding the eggs with some acrylic paints. Perhaps we were trying to be a bit too 'futuristic' by not going with a traditional stretched canvas, **as with later Data paintings**. Nothing wrong with going old school; after all, the Picard family still grew grapes and made wine pretty much the old-fashioned way, as far as we know."*
> <sub>from [this link](http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/database/space_art_tng.htm), that @chirlu [linked in the comments](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/149021/who-painted-datas-paintings#comment382485_149021), although I found it by Googling myself (emphasis mine)</sub>

This seems to imply that the artists behind the scenes painted at least some of Data's paintings. I can't seem to find anything on the specific one you mentioned, though.